# Bluetooth to uart module

Tags: android, bluetooth

which one is the best bluetooth to uart module? I want to connect the module with my controller and communicate with chip through android mobile. How can i do that? help me ...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have had excellent success with the FireFly modules.  Fair warning--they are expensive.  In any case, check here:

http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=firefly

Answer (score 0):

The RN42 module seems to do the job and supports SPP.

http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=506